# How can I use zip function for this?

Tags: python, zip

```
for i in range(2200):
    calculate_path(r_mercury, mercury_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_venus, venus_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_earth, earth_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_mars, mars_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_jupiter, jupiter_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_saturn, saturn_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_uranus, uranus_track, i)
    calculate_path(r_neptune, neptune_track, i)
```

This is the code, I would like to optimize it using zip, is there any way I can do that?

And the first And the first parameter of **calculate_path** is an int, second one is empty list, but I am appending values in function.

Comment: What is this `calculate_path` you speak of? Where are the iterables you want to zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call this optimizing since it doesn't improve anything, but here is a shorter implementation:

```
r_planets = [r_mercury, r_venus, r_earth]
planets_tracks = [mercury_track, venus_track, earth_track]

for i in range(2200):
    for r_planet, planets_track in zip(r_planets, planets_tracks):
        calculate_path(r_planet, planets_track, i)
```

Alternatively, with one less for loop (but still the same number of iteration anyway):

```
import itertools

r_planets = [r_mercury, r_venus, r_earth]
planets_tracks = [mercury_track, venus_track, earth_track]

for p, i in itertools.product(zip(r_planets, planets_tracks), range(2200)):
    r_planet = p[0] # can be remove
    planets_track = p[1] # can be remove
    calculate_path(r_planet, planets_track, i) # can be replace with calculate_path(p[0], p[1], i)
```